# Magento set data to block in magento way?

Tags: blocks

I'm studying Magento and I'm interested to know how to rewrite my code in "Magento way":

```
echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('...')
   ->setData('shipment', $this->getShipment())
   ->setData('order', $this->getOrder())
   ->toHtml();
```

So the question is about: How I can call setData from my config.xml files to get in my layout.phtml file something like this:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('block_name')
```

Or my current code is correct and there is nothing to refactor?

Comment: Can u please explain `How I can call setData from my config.xml`.I did not get ur point.

Comment: I have seen next code in xml configuration:
<block type="package/path_to_module" name="custome_name" template="package/path_to_view/items.phtml">
 <action method="addRender">
  <type>default</type>
  <block>adminhtml/sales_items_some_block</block>
  <template>package/path_to_view/items.phtml</template>
 </action>
</block>

As I understand it does some methods calls for every <action> tag with params. That’s why I asked community about calling "setData" directly from config...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $this->getChild('block_name')->setData(...)->toHtml()
```